# Objective-C: How to use memory management properly for asynchronous methods

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, asynchronous

I need to call a method that starts some asynchronous code

```
MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClass startAsynchronousCode];
```

Now I can't simply release it as this would cause an error since the code is still running:

```
[myClass release];  // causes an error
```

What is the best way to deal with the memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have -[MyClass startAsynchronousCode] invoke a callback:

```
typedef void(*DoneCallback)(void *);

-(void) startAsynchronousCode {
  // Lots of stuff
  if (finishedCallback) {
    finishedCallback(self);
  }
}
```

and then instantiate a MyClass like this:

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWith: myCallback];
```

myCallback might look like this:

```
void myCallback(void *userInfo) {
  MyClass *thing = (MyClass *)userInfo;
  // Do stuff
  [thing release];
}
```

Comment: When 'myCallback' method finishes wont the execution of the code return to the end of the method that called the callback: 'startAsynchronousCode' which has just been relesed?

Comment: Yes, which is why it's important that you really are done before invoking the callback. You won't get any access violations unless you refer to self after the callback.

Comment: I think you're asking "how is startAsynchronousCode asynchronous?" in your comment? The above idiom is meant for when you create a thread and run startAsynchronousCode from within that new thread.

Answer (score 3):

How are you invoking the asynchronous code?  If you use [NSThread +detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:), you'll find that the target object is retained by the thread until it terminates and then it is released. So you can release the object immediately after the asynchronous message.

e.g.

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void) startAsynchronousCode
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(threadMain:) toTarget: self withObject: nil];
}

-(void) threadMain: (id) anObject
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // do stuff
    [pool drain];
}
@end
```

With the above, the following code is perfectly safe:

```
MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClass startAsynchronousCode];
[myClass release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must retain your myClass object internally in startAsynchronousCode method. And release it internally too after it finished.

This behavior used in NSURLConnection, UIAlertView and other async objects.

Answer (score 0):

What I've always done is maintained an instance variable that points to the asynchronous object.

```
- (id)init {
    myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [myClass startAsynchronousCode];
}

- (void)myClassDidFinish:(MyClass *)myClass {
    [myClass release];
}
```